# C# WPF How to Pass an object of an observable collection from the property of the object

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

thank you for reading my question.

**Situation:**

I have an observable collection

```
CheckableTags = new ObservableCollection<CheckableListItem<Item>>();
```

The wrapper class `CheckableListItem<Item>` adds a bool per object Item.

```
public class CheckableListItem<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool mIsChecked;
    private T mItem;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public CheckableListItem(T item)
    {
        mItem = item;
    }

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get
        {
            return mIsChecked;
        }
        set
        {
            mIsChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
            MeasConSettings.Current.CheckableTags_CheckedChanged("ENTIRE OBJECT HERE");
        }
    }

    public T Item
    {
        get
        {
            return mItem;
        }
        set
        {
            mItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Item");
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

When the user checks the checkbox, the bool variable is changed, this is why I fire the function `MeasConSettings.Current.CheckableTags_CheckedChanged("ENTIRE OBJECT HERE");` in the property of the bool variable.

The function is as following:

```
public void CheckableTags_CheckedChanged(object sender)
{}
```

**My question is:**
How can I send the entire object from the property of the bool to the function in my viewmodel, what should I send in the field "ENTIRE OBJECT HERE" in order to receive an object of CheckableListItem class with 2 elements the bool variable and the Item.

If possible get a reference to the object so I can copy it in the receiving function.

**Alternatives:**
If this is not possible, what else can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the entire object using this keyword:

```
MeasConSettings.Current.CheckableTags_CheckedChanged(this);
```

Also you can change your method and class to use generics and accept a typed generic parameter like:

```
public void CheckableTags_CheckedChanged(CheckableListItem<T> sender)
{}
```